# The usage of "that" as a relative pronoun

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns

Under what condition should we use "that" as the required and ONLY relative pronoun?
Please give some examples.
Thanks!

Comment: If you ask CGEL, never, because _that_ isn't a relative pronoun at all in their view.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem with using technical language in a question. CGEL considers it a complementizer, if I recall correctly; but maybe I don't recall correctly. It certainly **was** a tensed clause complementizer in Chaucer's time (_Whan that Aprille..._) and it still is in modern English complement clauses, but I don't mind calling it an allomorph of _Wh_-pronouns.

Comment: @JohnLawler And I believe *Þæt* and other inflections of the article were employed as relativizers before the *hw-* forms were recruited to that use. The original complementizer was *Þe*; in effect, *the* and *that* switched places.

Comment: Right. And German uses articles for relatives still.

Answer (score 2):

There is *NO* circumstance in which the language requires a relative *that* and excludes use of a *wh-* relativizer or ‘null’ relativizer (no relativizer).

*That* is preferred by some writers (and most speakers) when the relative clause is restrictive, and this preference has been elevated to a ‘rule’ by some publishers and some writers on style; but the practice is not so generally observed that it can legitimately be called a ‘rule’ of the language itself.

There are contexts in which relative *that* is prohibited: *that* may not head a non-restrictive relative clause or follow a preposition at the head of relative clause. These are actual ‘rules’.

Comment: Actually, there are a few situations -- degenerate cases, essentially -- where _that_ can be used and a _Wh_-word can't: when the _Wh_-word would be _how_, for instance ( *the way how he did it). Same situation for a _why_-relative modifying any noun except _reason_ (*the purpose why he did it).

Comment: @JohnLawler True, in StdE. But *the way how* may be encountered in the vernacular, and in any case accommodates ∅. And I'd be even more uncomfortable with *the purpose **that** he did it*. It really calls for *the purpose that/which/∅ he did it **for***.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "that" as the only acceptable relative pronoun in the following sentences:

- "Everything that I said was criticized."
- "All the figs that fall are eaten by the pigs."
- "This is the best hotel that I know".

Using "which" in these examples would be grammatical but would also sound awkward to my ears. ("which" just doesn't sound correct after certain words like "everything", "all", "little", "much" and after "superlatives") Certainly, "that" can be omitted in the first and third examples, and the sentences would sound better.

Answer (score -1):

1. I know the boy. the boy stole my watch.
2. he was riding a horse. The horse was running fast.
3. The teacher call Rahul. Rahul came at once.

Comment: To present your examples as instances where _that_ is required, you need to show them as single sentences incorporating _that_, not merely as pairs of sentences that can be joined by _that_. Even then, you are likely to encounter disagreement from others here who may not be persuaded that your examples do indeed require _that_ as a joining word.